# Real time Database Firebase don't show root reference

Tags: android, firebase

[image]
It don't show root reference in database. I also access my database. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Oops! I also met the same problem a couple months before. The reason is due to your data is so much, so in your application, you need reset all saved data in Firebase by using method.

```
DatabaseReference mData;
mData = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
mData.child("*your-root-reference*").setValue("Reset database");
```